# Is there a (Windows) limit on number of characters in a Label Caption?

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl

I noticed that in a (Delphi 10.3.3 32-bit VCL app on Windows 10 64-bit) application that the caption of a label would not display if the string was "really" long. Further testing indicates that it is not restricted to a TLabel. TStaticText also behaves the same way and probably all of the TGraphicControls.

With a TLabel on a form, testing indicates that it will show the caption if it is 43,679 characters in length. But any longer and the caption disappears. No combination of autosize, wordwrap, EllipsisPosition changed this behaviour. Tracing through the delphi code, it comes down to 2 statments in VCL.Controls:

```
  Perform(WM_SETTEXT, 0, Buffer);
  Perform(CM_TEXTCHANGED, 0, 0);
```

Buffer holds the correct value of the caption's string in all cases. But at **43,680** chars the caption disappears. So it appears to be a Windows limit but I cannot find any confirmation of this.

Comment: [Perhaps something like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-limittext)

Comment: @MBo. Thanks. Doesn't look applicable: "The EM_LIMITTEXT message limits only the text the user can enter."

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: `TLabel` isn't a windowed control, so the first contact with the Windows API should be at `DrawText` or something similar.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue. I'm using Delphi 10.3.2 on Windows 7, 64-bit. I am currently looking at a 43691-character `TLabel` in a 32-bit VCL app.

Comment: Limit is not related with character string, I can duplicate it with just 4096 characters - one factor is font size. Label, graphic controls or in general VCL does not seem to have any part of it. This is how I duplicate: `var s: string; R: TRect; begin s := StringOfChar('a', 4096); R := ClientRect; DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s), -1, R, 0);`

Comment: Although missing in the code I commented, the function does not fail. Same with `DrawThemeTextEx`, what the label use when the app is styled - the function does not fail but content does not show. Limit is the same with DrawText and DrawThemeTextEx.

Comment: @Remy I am using Delphi 10.3.3; but have also reproduced problem with 10.4.1.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz "*when the app is styled*" - does the problem happen if the style is turned off?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I get no change in results when turning runtime themes off; styling is as per default (Windows); and no change in results if I change font size down a couple of steps.

Comment: @Remy - Yes, runtime themes makes no difference. I'm testing with XE2 (32 or 64 bits make no difference) on W7x64.